# Is it right to encode "+" and "-" in that way?

Tags: objective-c, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to encode string with UTF-8 format and all required characters instead of "+" and "-" are not formatted.

I investigated `NSCharacterSet`, and found out that standard `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` method is not fully covering my issue.

I decide to create own NSCharacterSet with symbols that should be replaced:

```
 NSCharacterSet *customCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \"#%/:<>?@[\\]^`{|}+-"] invertedSet];
```

This is working, but I am interested if it is right to do this replacement by my own, or maybe there is some standard methods that are doing this replacements that I do not find?

Comment: What are you trying to encode?

Comment: i am trying to encode + and -

Comment: As part of a URL?  Which part?

Comment: i have string "UTC+01:00" that should be encoded to "UTC%2B01%3A00"

Comment: `+` and `-` are valid characters in an URL.

Comment: @vadian so usage of custom NSCharacterSet is valid in this case ?

Comment: It means that `+` and `-` don't need to be escaped.

Comment: @vadian in my case i should escape all URL characters with + and -

Comment: Then your custom character set it the right solution.

Comment: @vadian could you please post you're comment as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitly need to encode also the valid characters `+` and `-` then your custom character set is the right solution.